# Snapping mesh together by a point without stretching the object

Tags: modeling, mesh, snapping, 3d-cursor

I'm trying to snap two mesh together. One is a cylinder and the other is half a sphere. I aligned the 3d cursor to the bottom center of the cylinder where I want the sphere to attach to. I don't know how to move/snap the flat side of the half sphere to the 3d cursor without stretching the object. If I select the entire sphere the center of the sphere snaps to the 3d cursor, and If i select just the flat face/flat face vertex, the shape gets stretch.

Any advice on how to do this?

[image]

Comment: unless there's something particularly special about the hemisphere, why not extrude the tube to its final extent and then bevel/fillet the outer edge : see this answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38866/47

Answer (score 2):

On the object you want to move move the origin to the face that should line up with the other object. In **Edit Mode** select the face and use **Snap Cursor to Selected** That will move the 3D cursor to the center of the face. Then switch to object mode and do **Transform Origin to 3D Cursor**.

[image]

Next, select the other object and, in **Edit Mode**, **snap** the cursor to the face you want to snap to. Exit edit mode, select the previous object (the hemisphere) and do **Snap Selection to Cursor**.

(The shortcut for the **Snap** tool is <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>

[image]

Comment: You could also use Snap tool set to Vertex mode by grabbing the sphere (assuming sphere and cylinder are joined in one object)

Answer (score 1):

As @Mr Zak suggest, if you're editing a single mesh, you can use *Snap to vertices*

1. Select all the vertices you want to move
2. The very last vertex you select will be "Active" (in your case, it could be the vertex at center of the circle)
3. Toggle Snap Mode to *Vertex* and Target to *Active*

[image: List item]

4. Drag + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to snap

[image]

5. Remove doubles if needed...